# Someone give me some help - Instagram (serious answers only please)

Tags: instagram

I was wondering if I liked a picture by accident on someones public profile (Instagram, also should be noted that neither party involved follows each other) and they in turn make there profile private at a later date, would the picture that I liked previously when their profile was public still be listed/available under my section of "post I liked"?

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem. Also, your title is not at all descriptive, then your question is in one block of text.

Answer (score 0):

The picture you liked will still be there, but you won't be able to see it unless you follow that person and he/she accepts your friendship/follow request.

So you will need to follow that person.